# django static files relative path does not work

Tags: python, regex, django, url, django-urls

I cahnged the static files defualt path

and added in url.py

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

It works fine for first level pages 
like

```
/login
/admin
/dahboard
```

but static files does not load when I go to second level pages

```
/admin/users/
/admin/users/add/
```

How I can fix this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `STATIC_URL` has a `/` at the beginning:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Otherwise, URL will be like `<img src="static/thing.png" />` which can work on first level (since it will search from the root) but not when you are in subdirectories.
Be aware the [`serve` method only work in DEBUG mode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve).